# Print out variables in Logger component in MuleSoft Anypoint Studio

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

If I want to use Logger Component to print variables, it looks like I have to go through below 4 steps

1. Firstly click “fx” symbol
2. At Message box write #[vars.employeeId],
3. Click “fx” symbol again
4. click save, otherwise I always see error shown on Logger component (marked with yellow color)

Is it work-as-design or it is a bug of anypoint studio IDE, any hints are more than welcome, thank you! [image]

Thanks for aled' explaining. i tried the fx button way, it works but IDE gives error hints as below shown. it is very confusing for user .
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the usage and syntax. That fx button is optional. It means that the message is a DataWeave expression. In the XML format of the flow it just encloses the entire message into an expression (`"#[ ... ]"`). If you are doing it the contents must be a valid DataWeave expression, so the string `#### employeeId ->` must be enclosed in double quotes and must be concatenated to the variable. Using the expression delimiters inside another expression delimiter is not valid. Since it is already an expression you just concatenate the variable: `"#### employeeId ->" ++ vars.employeeId`.

However if you don't use the fx button you can still use expressions inside the message, then `#### employeeId -> #[vars.employeeId]` is a valid message for the logger.

Comment: Thanks your reply, i tried your two suggestiones, both way works, but just the fx button way, it causes IDE with error hints, alhtough in praticse it works but it is very confusing for user. I assume it is IDE bug (I posted the IDE error hints for fx button way , please see it above)

Comment: That hint seems to indicate that Studio can not find that the variable has been defined prior to the logger. In that case its value will be null and null can not be concatenated to a string. If you already are defining the variable just ignore it.

Comment: i already defined this varible in advance , otherwise at runtime it could not work. how to get rid of such annoying hints? of couse i could just simply ingore it :-)

Comment: You can ignore it but ```(vars.employeeId default "")```. By defaulting you can try. @stewchicken